# How to skip "information_schema.sequences" creation while using Hibernate in Java projects

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift as a DB for my Java Project with Hibernate support. When the Hibernate starts, it tries to create a sequence, which I do not need.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;

    public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        if (SESSION_FACTORY == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                Properties settings = new Properties();
                settings.put("show_sql", "false");
                settings.put("current_session_context_class", "thread");
                settings.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
                configuration.setProperties(settings);

                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource)
                        .build();

                SESSION_FACTORY = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error creating Session Factory.", e);
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return SESSION_FACTORY; }
}
```

This is the stack trace.

```
ERROR [2019-06-07 14:41:40,743] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
! com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;
! ... 52 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;
```

Comment: hibernate version you use?

Comment: <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

<version>5.4.2.Final</version>

Comment: first of all check whether your database support this kind of query (select * 
from information_schema.sequences). if it doesn't , HB configuration has picked wrong dialect.

Comment: Redshift does not support this kind of query (select * from information_schema.sequences). Error is [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;

Comment: The dialect Hibernate picked is org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

Comment: @VinayLimbare Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a custom Dialect that overrode existing PostgreSqlDialect

```
    public class CustomRedshiftDialect extends PostgreSQL81Dialect {

    @Override
    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the HibernateUtil class or the appropriate XML.

```
        // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.put("show_sql", "false");
    settings.put("current_session_context_class", "thread");
    settings.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    settings.put("hibernate.dialect", "com.me.vlimbare.factory.db.CustomRedshiftDialect");
```